# Kotlin: inline function and shared type

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-inline-class

I want to call multiple API calls at once using coroutines. So far I used coroutines only to call single API call which returned result in form off success or error. Its using inline function. But I need to understand how to use this inline function parameter for data class.

Class `JsonResponse` is open class which is result for every single API call. But if I use `T` inside my data class, its red. If I use there type `JsonResponse`, it is returning `JsonResponse` type, but not that exact type what `apiBlock` suppose to return.

Example: `apiBlock` can contain task, which will return `LoginResponse`. LoginResponse is extending `JsonResponse`. But if I use `JsonResponse` instead `T` inside my data class, I will have generic `JsonResponse` inside my `onSuccess` callback.

My goal here is to initialize multiple tasks, run them inside coroutine as async, then wait for all tasks to finish and if some of them will fail, return failed ones as array so they can be called again.

Here is code what I want to achieve:

```
data class ApiTask(
        val apiBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T,
        val onSuccess: suspend (T)->Unit)
protected fun<T: JsonResponse> apiCallChained(
        apiBlocks: List<ApiTask>,
        onError: ((List<ApiTask>)->Unit),
        onSuccess: ()->Unit){

        val failedTasks = mutableListOf<ApiTask>()
        apiBlocks.forEach { apiBlock->
            launch(Dispatchers.Main){
                val (r, err) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                    try {
                        apiBlock.apiBlock(this) to null
                    } catch (e: ApiCallError) {
                        null to e
                    }
                }

                when {
                    r != null -> {
                        apiBlock.onSuccess(r)
                    }
                    err != null -> failedTasks.add(apiBlock)
                }
            }
        }

        if (failedTasks.isEmpty()) onSuccess.invoke() else onError.invoke(failedTasks)
 }
```

Here is my working example for single API call:

```
protected fun<T: JsonResponse> apiCall(apiBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T,
                                              onError: ((ApiCallError)->Unit)? = null,
                                              onDone: (()->Unit)? = null,
                                              onSuccess: suspend (T)->Unit): Job {

        return launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            val (r, err) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                try {
                    apiBlock() to null
                } catch (e: ApiCallError) {
                    null to e
                }
            }
            onDone?.invoke()
            when {
                r != null -> onSuccess(r)
                err != null -> {
                    onError?.invoke(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of ApiBlock parameter value:

```
class ApiLogin(js: JSONObject): JsonResponse(js) {

    companion object {
        @Throws(ApiCallError::class)
        operator fun invoke(api: AppApi, email: String, pass: String): ApiLogin{
            return ApiLogin(api.apiLoginUser(email, pass))
        }
    }

    class LoginServerResponse(js: JSONObject): JsonResponse(js){
        val httpCode by JsInt("httpCode")
        val session by JsString("session")
    }

    val r = LoginServerResponse(js)

}
```

This class is then used as

```
apiBlock = { ApiLogin(app.api, email, pass) }
```

UPDATE:
Fixed it like this, its working.

```
data class ApiTask<out T: JsonResponse>(
            val apiBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T,
            val onSuccess: suspend (@UnsafeVariance T)->Unit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ApiTask` also needs a generic parameter:

```kotlin
data class ApiTask<T : JsonResponse>(
    val apiBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T,
    val onSuccess: suspend (T) -> Unit
)
```

Then you have to add this generic parameter in the `apiCallChained` function too:

```kotlin
protected fun <T : JsonResponse> apiCallChained(
    apiBlocks: List<ApiTask<T>>,
    onError: ((List<ApiTask<T>>) -> Unit),
    onSuccess: () -> Unit
) {
    val failedTasks = mutableListOf<ApiTask<T>>()
    apiBlocks.forEach { apiBlock ->
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val (r, err) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    apiBlock.apiBlock(this) to null
                } catch (e: ApiCallError) {
                    null to e
                }
            }

            when {
                r != null -> {
                    apiBlock.onSuccess(r)
                }

                err != null -> failedTasks.add(apiBlock)
            }
        }
    }

    if (failedTasks.isEmpty()) onSuccess.invoke() else onError.invoke(failedTasks)
}
```

Comment: This solution is still returning object of type JsonResponse inside onSuccess instead of LoginResponse

Comment: You also have to modify the method `apiCallChained`, I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Ive done that. But its still returning wrong type

Comment: Where is the wrong type? In `apiBlock.onSuccess`?

Comment: yes - https://i.imgur.com/ub8i6Nk.png comparison. Its returning open Class which is extending ApiEmailLogin. It should return ApiEmailLogin and not JsonPreferences (JsonResponse)

Comment: It seems like it doesnt know that T suppose to be class which is extending JsonResponse and not JsonResponse itself. It is basically returning abstract class type (open class) which is generic response class